# How to run the command in deployment?

Tags: kubernetes

I have the following deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  namespace: dev
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
      containers:
      - name: keycloak
        image: "hub.svc.databaker.io/service/keycloak:0.1.8"
        imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
        command:
        - "-Dkeycloak.migration.action=import -Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled -Dkeycloak.migration.dir=/opt/jboss/keycloak/import-dir -Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=OVERWRITE_EXISTING"
```

And it can not be deployed. The error message is:

```
CrashLoopBackOff: back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=keycloak pod=keycloak-86c677456b-tqk6w_dev(6fb23dcc-9fe8-42fb-98d0-619a93f74da1)
```

I guess because of the command.

I would like to run a command analog to docker:

```
keycloak:
    networks:
      - auth
    image: hub.svc.databaker.io/service/keycloak:0.1.7
    container_name: keycloak
    command:
     - "-Dkeycloak.migration.action=import -Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled -Dkeycloak.migration.dir=/opt/jboss/keycloak/import-dir -Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=OVERWRITE_EXISTING"
```

How to run a command in K8S deployment?

**Update**

I have changed the deployment to:

```
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
      containers:
      - name: keycloak
        image: "hub.svc.databaker.io/service/keycloak:0.1.8"
        imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
        args:
         - "-Dkeycloak.migration.action=import"
         - "-Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir"
         - "-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled"
         - "-Dkeycloak.migration.dir=/opt/jboss/keycloak/import-dir"      
         - "-Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=OVERWRITE_EXISTING"
```

and receive the error:

```
RunContainerError: failed to start container "012966e22a00e23a7d1f2d5a12e19f6aa9fcb390293f806e840bc007a733c1b0": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"-Dkeycloak.migration.action=import -Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled -Dkeycloak.migration.dir=/opt/jboss/keycloak/import-dir -Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=OVERWRITE_EXISTING\": stat -Dkeycloak.migration.action=import -Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled -Dkeycloak.migration.dir=/opt/jboss/keycloak/import-dir -Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=OVERWRITE_EXISTING: no such file or directory": unknown
```

Comment: The error you provided shows that the initial command of `./standalone.sh` is missing. Please add it as a command as user @abinet suggested and check if it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your container has an entrypoint already you can provide the arguments only. This can be done with `args`. To define or override the entrypoint use `command`.

```
keycloak:
    networks:
      - auth
    image: hub.svc.databaker.io/service/keycloak:0.1.7
    container_name: keycloak
    command: ["./standalone.sh"]
    args:
     - "-Dkeycloak.migration.action=import"
     - "-Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir"
     - "-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled"
     - "-Dkeycloak.migration.dir=/opt/jboss/keycloak/import-dir"      
     - "-Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=OVERWRITE_EXISTING"
```